# How to make all xml request in one?

Tags: php, xml, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a webpage contains a lot of information; part of them is from the database (queries) and part is from remote xml files (http requests).

I want to know if it is possible to get the files together in one request.

I use the following instruction to get the xml files using php:

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feed/soccer/d1');

.
.
.

$xml5 = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feed/soccer/d5');
```

Is there a way to get the whole file as one in one request? because the page is slow and i think that is because of those links. (SQL queries are optimized).

Comment: Not unless the api has an endpoint for all. You could load the page without this data, then grab it via ajax, to give the impression of faster loading

Comment: Or you could cache the results if they dont change all the time

Comment: The data can not be cached changing data

Comment: what do u mean by end point for all. they are different files in the same directories

Comment: What makes you think they are physical files in directories? do you own the external site as well? And by endpoint for all, i mean eg: http://www.example.com/feed/soccer/all or http://www.example.com/feed/soccer?start=d1&end=d5

Comment: No there is nothing like this link.
example.com/feed/soccer/all or example.com/feed/soccer?start=d1&end=d5

Comment: In that case, the only thing i can think of is grabbing all 5 files in parallel with curl multi then loading them into simpexml from the local copies

Comment: Do u think the overhead and delay of using curl multi and then call them locally five times will be less than my case?